# Execute $interval after a function does not apply changes for other users Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i use $interval to call a function everey 5 seconds to apply changes without refreshing the page when multiple users connects.
But i would like to execute $interval after the function editCheque. So i put it in this function,it works but only for the current user and changes does not apply for the other users. Have you any solution to fixe this problem? Thanks

```
$interval(function() { $scope.chargerCheques(); }, 5000);

$scope.chargerCheques=function(){
        $http({
            method: 'get', 
            url: 'cheque'
        }).then(function (response) {       
            $scope.cheques = response.data;
            $scope.init=true;
            $scope.sumCurrentDate();
        },function (error){
            console.log(error, 'can not get data.');
        });
    };  

$scope.editCheque=function(){

.....
}
```

Comment: Please clarify, your question makes no sense...

Comment: Ok, i have an application, and when many users connects, when someone modify something, with $interval the modification will be applied for all the other users without refreshing the whole page because i call the function every n seconds. But when i put $interval inside the function editCheque, it make modification only for the user who click on modify button, but for the others they need to refresh the page to see the modification.